# Navigation Properties in .NetCore3.1 return null value

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am saving an model in database and after that I need to send notification to the user.

For example I am saving a User address and after saving the address in database I need to send notification to the user that address has been added in message I need some user properties which should be navigable from Address.

```
Entities
-----------------
public class User{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public ICollection<Address> Users {get; set;}
}

public class Address{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int UserId {get; set;}
 public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```

```
Address address = new Address(){name = "abc"};
unitOfWork.Repository.Add(address)
unitOfWork.Commit()
var savedAddress =  unitOfWork.Repository.GetById(address.Id); <---- User Navigation property return null
```

But if I try to find some other address, User Navigation property is not null, its only null when I save the address and immediately after that Get the saved address User Navigation Property is Null.

Lazy loading is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Address address = new Address {Name = "abc", UserId=<existing user id> };
```

And by the way fix the name:

```
public class User{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user property is null because in your code you are not associating any user with your address. Try adding the created address to the Addresses Collection of an user and saving it (and make sure that in your repository you include the user property when querying the address).